# Is there anything like a foreach for a BindingSource?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, database-connection

I am building a program to allow my boss to filter a list of actors by their skills / age / gender, and one thing she's asked for is the ability to email every person who fit the criteria with a single click.

I am using a listbox to list all of my actors, and I have filtering working just fine. What I can't figure out is how to run a foreach for every item in the filtered BindingSource and pull the email address.

So, I ask... **is there anything like a foreach for a BindingSource?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you filtered your `BindingSource` using its `Filter` property, you can access the filtered items via the `List` property (which is an `IList`, but you can cast it to your collection type).

Comment: Well, that works, but now I realize I have no idea how a BindingSource is populated from my Access database.  You did help me move into a new set of Google searches, so that's progress.  Thanks. :)